# Render component in dynamically appended HTML after Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Use case:

I have the dependency of a JQuery Library which appends HTML dinamically after some Ajax requests. I would like to display Vue components inside the appended HTML. I can supply the content of the HTML, but I can't change the way it gets appended to the DOM using JQuery.

I have no choice but to render the component when the Ajax request finnishes and the HTML was appended to the DOM.

What would be the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" approach is highly subjective.

However, you can certainly attach a component to an element if you know the element id:

```
import component from 'Component.vue'
new Vue({
    el: '#targetId',
    render: h => h(component)
})
```

This assumes that you are using single file components.  You can always create the component on the fly as well per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#targetId',
  // options
})
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any "performance throwback". Im using an external grid component which lets me add table details between rows. Could that approach be a problem if the user clicks through, lets say 100 rows?

Comment: It's tough to say but it probably isn't optimal. If I understand you correctly you'd essentially be creating 100 Vue components?  There definitely will be overhead but you'd have to test it and profile it to see if there is a performance hit.